# For a positive integer $k$, let $B_{k}=\{\,x \in \Bbb Z \mid x \leq 2k\,\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need a simple explanation on what the answer is to  $B_{k}=\{\,x \in \Bbb Z \mid x \leq 2k\,\}$. 
Question asks: Determine $\bigcup_{k=1}^{2016} B_{k} =?$

I understand the it will go on like $B_{1}...B_{2016}$ with the Union in between them. But what are they asking me to find? The set of choices of given answers were A.) $\Bbb Z$, B.) Set of even integers $\leq 2016$, C.) Set of positive integers $\leq 1008$, D.) Set of integers $\leq 2016$, and E.) None of the above.

The answer was E.) None of the above. I know I can cancel out options A.), B.), C.) and D.) but what's the right answer? I know the answer should be "Set of integers _ " But how do I obtain the underline number? Is it 2? 
If someone can clearly help me explaining this, that will be great. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That set is exactly $B_{2016}$, just because $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset B_3 \subset ...$.

Comment: In the language used in most of the options. the union is the set of all integers $\le 4032$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what would "the set of integers $5$" mean?  You're looking for "The set of integers such that $\underline{\text{some condition holds}}$" and what to know what the condition is.

When you don't immediately see how to do one of these problems, always work out the first few sets. \begin{align}
B_1 &= \{x \in \Bbb{Z} \mid x \leq 2 \cdot 1 \} = (-\infty, 2] \\
B_2 &= \{x \in \Bbb{Z} \mid x \leq 2 \cdot 2 \} = (-\infty, 4] \\
B_3 &= \{x \in \Bbb{Z} \mid x \leq 2 \cdot 3 \} = (-\infty, 6]  \text{.}
\end{align}

Ah.  Because $2k < 2(k+1)$, $B_k \subset B_{k+1}$.  This means the union is the same as its last member, $B_{2016} = \{x \in \Bbb{Z} \mid x \leq 2 \cdot 2016 \} = (-\infty, 4032]$.  This is the set of integers less than $4032$.

Comment: Oh I see, should it be less than 4032 not 4026? And will a similar procedure apply to intersection? If everything remains the same as the above question?

Comment: D'oh.  Fixing the typo' right at the end...

Comment: No.  The intersections will always be $B_1$ (for the same reason: $B_1 \subset B_k$ for all $k$).

Comment: So the answer would be "Set of integers less than 2"? So basically for a union we check for more conditions such as $B_{1}...B_{2016}$ and for  intersections we just go with $B_{1}$ condition only? Sorry, I am trying to simplify to myself, that way it can help me keep it in my brain longer.